# jQuery UI dialog - dynamic div - function sequence issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've got a div that I am appending to the page dynamically on click of a link, and then writing an iframe to that div.

```
// open login popin
function loginLayer(){
    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("destroy");
    callIframe();
    openLoginDialog();
}


// write dialog div & iframe + src to DOM
function callIframe() {

    var iframeURL = "" + loginConfig.iframeSource + "?displayType=" + loginConfig.displayType +"&isSignature=" + loginConfig.isSignature + ""
    $('body').append('<div id="loginDialog"></div>');
    $('#loginDialog').append('<IFRAME id="loginLayer" name="loginLayer" src="' + iframeURL + '" scrolling="no" width="100%"  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"  frameborder="0"></div>');
}


// open login dialog
function openLoginDialog(){ //open }
```

after `callIframe` runs, the dialog opens.

What's happening is that the dialog opens with the iframe, no issue - but, at the bottom of the `body` (firefox and IE) is a large amount of white space that is the same size as the `#loginDialog` height.

I'm not sure the cause, as everything appears in order - but it appears that when the div is appended to the body, that it's rendering there - increasing body height and then opening in the dialog.

**Edit**

Appears that it's a timing issue - if I step through each action using breakpoints, the problem is resolved - so something is triggering too soon...

If I do this, it works - so something in callIframe?:

```
callIframe();
alert('works when interrupted by alert');
openLoginDialog();
```

then, there's no issue. So, that means

Comment: Can you try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/7TtrN/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be written in cleaner way and I think it's the url that making the problem

```
function callIframe()
{
    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("destroy");
    var iframeURL = loginConfig.iframeSource + "?displayType=" + loginConfig.displayType + "&isSignature=" + loginConfig.isSignature;​
    var iframe=$('<iframe></iframe>', {
        src:iframeURL,
        id:'loginLayer',
        name:'loginLayer',
        width:'100%',
        marginheight:0,
        marginwidth:0,
        frameborder:0
    });
    $('<div id="loginDialog"></div>').html(iframe).dialog();
}

callIframe();
```

[**An Example Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/7TtrN/1/)

**Update:** According to your need [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/7TtrN/2/) is an updated fiddle.

Comment: The functions need to remain separate - I reworked your suggestion to fit the 3 functions - I'm still getting the issue. I think it's a timing issue, overall.

Comment: Can you give me your generated `iframeURL` ?

Comment: `loginLayer.html?displayType=login&isSignature=false`

Comment: Everything seems fine to me, not sure what's happening. the demo is also working in both browsers IE and FF in same way.

Comment: May be you can set the height of the div in px, i.e. `$('<div id="loginDialog" style="height:300px;"></div>').html(iframe).dialog();`

Comment: right, I can't keep it all in one function that way - your demo is great, I just can't use it. So looking at my original functions, is there a way to ensure the sequence is correct.

Comment: Great answers, and I'll give you credit. I ended up fixing this with: `create: function(event, ui){
    
    //dialog has display errors without
    $('.ui-dialog').css("position", "absolute");`

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be causing due to not closing the `iframe` tag.

Replace this line

```
$('#loginDialog').append('<IFRAME id="loginLayer" name="loginLayer" src="' + iframeURL + '" scrolling="no" width="100%"  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"  frameborder="0"></div>');
```

to this

```
$('#loginDialog').append('<iframe id="loginLayer" name="loginLayer" src="' + iframeURL + '" scrolling="no" width="100%"  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"  frameborder="0"></iframe>');
```

Comment: unfortunately, that's not it. It appears to be a timing issue - but I'm not sure where it's getting hung up. If I step through each action using breakpoints, it works fine. So something is triggering too soon....

Answer (score 0):

The real cause:

I was dynamically loading the css as well, and the css wasn't fully processing before the dialog opened, causing the issues...